# How to get muli-language (human language) intellisense in .Net

Tags: .net, intellisense, culture, xml-comments

I'm creating a library (C#, .Net), but I need to distribute it to customers in multiple countries.  When you add XML comments to your classes, intellisense picks up the comments out of the assembly and gives you a nice description of your methods, properties, arguments, etc...

Is there any way I can make localized versions of my assembly so the XML comments are in the language of the locale, yet only have to maintain one copy of my source code?

Comment: IMO it is OK to have the descriptions in English only. Every developer should be able to understand English.

Comment: You would have to translate the comments, which I doubt you want to do, comments cannot be converted to another language automatically.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't expect any software to translate my comments to another language.  I just want to be able to choose the comments of the appropriate language when I compile the assembly

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an pretty old one, but it was the first hit to my google-query, so I would like to post my answer here for other google-users on this topic.

Yet, I don't know any tool which translates your xml-comments automatically, but if you do the translation for yourself, you can store the translated xml-file with the same name as the original one in a sub-folder, named by the targeted locale.

So I have my localized resources in a sub-folder 'de', where all German translated xml-comment files and localized satellite assemblies are stored.

When I reference my assembly, IntelliSense shows the localized texts, as the running application uses the localized strings.